# awscli stopped working after upgrading python 3.6 to 3.7

Tags: aws-cli

Python has been upgraded from 3.6 to 3.7 on my mac and my awscli stopped working , I get this error every time I try use awscli commands :
-bash: /Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.6/bin/aws: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I have tried different things but none of them solved my issue. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to refer python3.6 aws cli and which is internally referring to  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6 which doesn't exist.

solution is upgrade aws and also refer aws from python3.7